# Why is there an inconsistency between the location of the flag notification?

Tags: support, notification-bar

As a moderator on SQA, I see moderator flags. Here's an example of my bar with the notification:

[image: SQA notification bar]

However, as a high rep user on Board and Card games, I see the occasional flag there too. Here's an example of that bar.

[image: BCG notification bar]

My poor brain gets very confused. Why is it on one side on one site and another side on another site? And is it desirable behavior? Shouldn't flags be flags be flags?

Comment: They're in two different queues; you didn't really expect them to be in the same place, did you?

Comment: Considering they do almost exactly the same thing, it seems inconsistent to have them in different places. Suggested edits are also in a different queue, but that shows up right next to flags (tools flags)